# Why does applicationhost.config keeps getting encrypted

Tags: windows-7, iis

Every so often my ApplicationHost.config gets encrypted and I'm not sure why.
Can someone help?

Encrypted Broken ApplicationHost.config

[image: Encrypted Broken ApplicationHost.config]

Normal backed up ApplicationHost.config

[image]

Comment: You have configured IIS to encrypt your configuration files. I am going to guess you are on some sort of shared server configured considering IIS supports doing that. We need more specific details. You can change this behavior through `IIS Manager` provided you have the required permissions in order to do so. Of course the file itself supports being encrypted so its not clear the reason you believe its "broken".  My suggestion is to export the encrypted configuration file to which settings are different.

Comment: How do you turn this off in IIS?

Comment: I explained how to turn it off in my comment.  But if it's a shared hosting environment your unlikely going to have the permission to do so

Comment: @Ramhound, this isn't a shared host, this is my local computer. You told me to turn it off in IIS Manager, but where? I don't have shared configuration enabled.